# Quais são os tipos de autenticações suportadas pelo HTTP?

Tags: http, autenticação, autenticação-http

Pretendo me aprofundar mais em autenticações que estão no contexto do protocolo HTTP, porém, eu desconheço seus tipos.

Sendo assim, eu gostaria de uma explicação breve em relação as autenticações suportadas pelo HTTP e como elas funcionam.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Basic:** O Basic Authentication é o sistema de autenticação mais comum do protocolo HTTP. Ele é incluído no header da requisição HTTP dessa maneira:

```
Authorization: Basic {credenciais em base 64 no formato usuário:senha}
```

Lembre que o Base 64 é um esquema de codificação e não criptografia. Assim sendo, você DEVE utilizá-lo somente com uma conexão HTTPS (TLS). O uso do Base 64 se deve ao padrão MIME.

**Bearer:** Bearer authentication (também conhecido como token authentication) é um Schema para autenticação HTTP (RC6750).

```
Authorization: Bearer <token>
```

O Bearer identifica recursos protegidos por um OAuth2. O  deve ser um string. Ele representa uma autorização do Server emitida para o client. Por sua vez, o client deve possuir mecanismos próprios para identificar e validar o Token.

**Digest:** A autenticação digest é um método de autenticação no qual uma solicitação de um usuário em potencial é recebida por um servidor de rede e, em seguida, enviada para um controlador de domínio. O controlador de domínio envia uma chave especial, chamada de chave de sessão digest, ao servidor que recebeu a solicitação original. O usuário deve então produzir uma resposta, que é criptografada e transmitida ao servidor. Se a resposta do usuário for da forma correta, o servidor concede ao usuário acesso à rede, ao site ou aos recursos solicitados para uma única sessão.

Além dessas principais, há também as autenticações HOBA, Mutual e AWS4-HMAC-SHA256, que são mostradas nesse link (https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTTP/Authentication).

Links interessantes para maiores detalhes:

**Basic:** http://qnimate.com/understanding-http-authentication-in-depth/

**Bearer:** https://www.brunobrito.net.br/jwt-cookies-oauth-bearer/

**Digest:** https://searchsecurity.techtarget.com/definition/digest-authentication

**Mutual:** https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/ssl_mutual_about.htm

**AWS4-HMAC-SHA256:** https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-auth-using-authorization-header.html